# How can I resolve the `package mysql-server is not installed` issue?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, ssh

I have just upgraded MySQL from version 5.5.55 to version 5.6, via SSH.  I have managed to successfully start the MySQL, however I am experiencing the `500 Internal Server Error` when trying to access the website on the server as well as generating the Apache Test page when trying to access the Webmail.

I then ran the command `rpm -q mysql-server`, where I received the following response:

```
package mysql-server is not installed
```

From the above's output, I assume that MySQL has not been installed.  However, when I enter `mysql --version`, the following is outputted:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.44, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Furthermore, when I run the command `yum install mysql-server`, I also receive the output of:

```
Package mysql-community-server-5.6.44-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

As such, I am confused and not sure whether MySQL is actually installed or not.

In order to resolve this issue, and allow access back to the website and Mail Domain, what would be the next step I would need to perform?

Comment: `mysql --version` is the client; it tells you nothing about the MySQL server. Also, what leads you to believe that "500 Internal Server Error" has any relation to MySQL?

Comment: @mustaccio:  The '500 Internal Server Error' message had only started as soon as I updated the MySQL.  At present, I cannot get into Plesk, so restricted to SSH.  How would I go about installing the MySQL Server?